# Remove unused applications?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)

I'm running low on hard drive space and have been prompted to remove unused applications. Is there a way to find unused applications/programs in Ubuntu 10.4. I have removed several applications in the software center. My concern is that with the Ubuntu updates I will run out of space soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to run

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

It will clear out all the cached files that have been downloaded in the past. It should save you some disk space.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gain space, you are maybe interested in the following [apt-get options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3167/what-is-difference-between-the-options-autoclean-autoremove-and-clean)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's updates won't need more disk space as they are incremential ,ie they replace the old installed version, but of course many new features may slighlty increase the size of the package but I have sen that sometimes an update frees some space.

If you want to clear and delete several cache and log files , I recommend you to instal and run bleachbit.