# apt-get: how to make it keep old archives locally when upgrading packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I know I can't install previous version without a local copy of the archive of needed version. But today I found out something surprising: I was sure that all previous archives are stored in cache. But after I upgraded firefox from v28 to v29 and checked available versions to install, result is unexpected for me:

```
$ apt-cache madison firefox
firefox | 29.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
firefox | 29.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main i386 Packages
firefox | 11.0+build1-0ubuntu4 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

There is no version 28. I checked `/var/cache/apt/archives`, and there is actually no archive of version 28. That is sad that it is removed.

How can I prevent it from removing old archives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apt cache is managed by a daily cron job. To modify the default settings, open (as root) `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive`:

```
APT::Archives::MaxAge "30";
APT::Archives::MinAge "2";
APT::Archives::MaxSize "500";
```

To disable the automatic removal, set the three values to `0`.

See the top of of `/etc/cron.daily/apt` for a brief documentation of these options.

Comment: Yeah thanks: I have another computer without this file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive` (no idea why btw, OS is the same and up-to-date as well), I just checked apt cache archive on it, and there are many old versions of the packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From `man apt-get`

> **autoclean:**
>   Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved
>   package files. The difference is that it only removes package files
>   that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless. This allows
>   a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing out of
>   control. **The configuration option APT::Clean-Installed will prevent
>   installed packages from being erased if it is set to off.**

Check what the current value is with `apt-config dump|grep Clean`

In `/etc/apt/apt.conf` add:

```
APT::Clean-Installed "false";
```

Also see [What is difference between the options “autoclean”, “autoremove” and “clean”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3167/what-is-difference-between-the-options-autoclean-autoremove-and-clean)

Comment: But I haven't executed `autoclean`, I just upgraded the package. In manual, I can't find that autoclean is executed automatically after upgrading the package. To be honest I can't check it now, because now all the packages are up-to date, and there is nothing to upgrade, so I have to wait until something new will come

Comment: Do you run unattended-upgrades or any other cron job that would call autoclean?

Comment: No. I had non-zero values in the `etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive` as @SylvainPineau mentioned, but they should not affect the package right away after upgrading

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the information and for trying to help.