# Crackling Sound after latest update

Tags: sound

Totally new to Ubuntu and Linux.
Installed 14.04 on clean machine about two weeks ago. not much installed but playonlinux (Diablo 3), wine (diablo 3), gksu, etc.
Was able to fix audio issues initially by doing step 1B from here:
[Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).

Looks like a kernel patch came in this week.
Something must have gone wrong because on reboot, no dice. NO recovery option would successfully boot.

So I reinstalled 14.04 again (erased disk)
can boot, but cannot fix audio. Tried the step 1B and Step 1C from above. crackling is awful (rhythmbox, youtube, wine especially)

I have run

```
apt-get update
```

- tried tsched=0 fix - caused rhythmbox to crash when attempting to play mp3.
- tried setting the intel hd model to generic.

MOBO is GA-Z97-HD3 (has ALC887)

Please help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/477087/does-ubuntu-uninstall-unnecessary-updates

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to the new Z97 motherboard that you're using. The issue is specified in launchpad here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1321421

If the solution in launchpad doesn't work for you, you might be able to resolve the issue by installing the latest linux kernel which I wrote instructions on here:

https://github.com/Nerdylicious/How_To_Fix_Ubuntu_Compatibility_On_Intel_Z97_Build