# How to remove kernel?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, configuration

I have installed two kernel version 3.10.48 and 3.17.6 for project. As I am not requiring 3.10.48 any more, I wanted to remove that version as it is taking up almost 10GB of my disk space. How should I go about it?

Comment: You can refer the url to remove the kernal. http://askubuntu.com/questions/564227/right-way-to-completely-clean-up-old-kernels-in-terminal/565225#565225

Comment: In what world does a kernel binary take 10 GB? O.o

Comment: I would recommend leaving it, in case something goes wrong, you have a fall back.

Comment: I am totally agree with @Mitch. Instead of removing it, see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/529797/how-to-find-out-the-top-space-consuming-directories-or-files) to find which files and folders are consuming your disk space. As Muru said, kernal will not consume 10 GB of space.

Comment: @priyanka-naik Do you mean that you have pulled the kernel sources from repositories and those are occupying that much of your disk space? Clarifying this will help people to answer to your "problem".

Answer (score -1):

First boot the Kernel which you want to retain. Then use the below command to remove Kernel from your machine permanently,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your command does nothing

Answer (score -1):

I think the 10Gb is for compiling you can clean it just by :
1. you should open the directory where you compile the source of kernel:
example: cd /usr/src/linux
after that use his command to clean all files genarated in the compiling process:

```
make clean
```

or 
in the case that you compile the kernel with make-kpkg you should clean it by:

```
make-kpkg clean
```

or you should try one of those processes :

## 1. For uninstalling the kernel run:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-version_number*

sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-version_number*

sudo apt-get remove linux-image-extra-version_number*     (if applicable)
```

or simply uninstall them from synaptic/software center.

## 2. For uninstalling the kernel installed from source, run:

```
sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/kernel_version

sudo rm -f /boot/vmlinuz-kernel_version*

sudo rm -f /boot/initrd.img-kernel_version*

sudo rm -f /boot/config-kernel_version*

sudo rm -f /boot/System.map-kernel_version*
```

Finally, after uninstalling the kernel by either one of the processes above, run:

sudo update-grub

to clean the grub menu.