# How to determine obsolete kernels and remove them to clean up disk space

Tags: kernel, disk-usage, cleanup

[image]

- I want to clean disk space
- Disk analyzer shows this graph
- I noticed the repetitive pattern in `/lib/modules` (I guess old kernel versions)

## How to determine obsolete kernels?

### How to remove them safely?

> Already tried `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt autoclean` as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/715441/299951); these had no effect.

*edit - why differs my question from the suggested duplicate: A simple solution like the one-liners I already tried would be nice, as I prefer a "user-friendly" way to work with my computer instead of using cryptic terminal-commands*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/usr/bin/purge-old-kernels` it's in the `byobu` package. `purge-old-kernels` handles the details (deleting all the parts of the old kernel, not deleting your current kernel, etc).

Comment: deleted 3.5GB with one command - works great. I hope also after reeboot ;) Official man page of the script btw: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/purge-old-kernels.1.html

Answer (score 2):

Get a list of all kernels that are installed on your Ubuntu:

```
dpkg -l "*linux-image-*" | grep ^ii
```

check which one of them you are running:

```
uname -r
```

Remove everything except the one which is in `uname -r` outputs:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge linux-image ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### ***"I prefer a "user-friendly" way to work with my computer instead of using cryptic terminal-commands"***

[image: rm-kernels]

`rm-kernels` fits your "user friendly" requirement. It's a bash script you can quickly create. As described in **Ask Ubuntu** answer: [How to selectively purge old kernels all at once](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once/892077#892077)