# Error installing mysql-server-5.5

Tags: apt, upgrade, mysql

I am trying to run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But it gaves me below output. I tried to run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but there isn't any difference.

```
(Reading database ... 621055 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.46-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.46-0+deb8u1) over (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.46-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz', which is also in package mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.46-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also i tried to run `dpkg --configure -a`, but its helpless too. The output is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.46-0+deb8u1); however:
  Version of mysql-client-5.5 on system is 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you tried to install mysql-client-core-5.6 first.

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.6
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: No need for `autoclean` right?

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/a/3169/145133