# Slow boot on 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 20.04

Thanks Czar for responding.
Edits:
I timed the boot with a stopwatch from the Grub menu and it was 2 minutes and 17 seconds
systemd-analyze reports 1 min 28 seconds
Not sure why there is this difference
My graphics is a Radeon 5450 [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]

The output of journalctl was immense and too long to paste here. In factit was 403MB of data.
Output of lsblk -f is:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL                           UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/core/8935
loop1  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/core/9066
loop2  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/core18/1705
loop3  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/core18/1754
loop4  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop5  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
loop6  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/27
loop7  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop8  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop9  squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/mc-installer/488
loop10 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/mc-installer/496
loop11 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/minetest/1370
loop12 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/minetest/1521
loop13 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/quake-shareware/10
loop14 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/quake-shareware/14
loop15 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/quakespasm-beidl/45
loop16 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/snap-store/433
loop17 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/vlc/1397
loop18 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/vlc/1620
loop19 squashfs                                                                            0   100% /snap/yamagi-quake2-beidl/40
sda                                                                                                 
├─sda1 ntfs     System Reserved                 DEAC9B64AC9B364D                                    
├─sda2 ntfs                                     48B49D12B49D039A                                    
├─sda3 ntfs                                     30A404C2A4048C92                                    
├─sda4                                                                                              
└─sda5 ext4                                     09bbb74b-60e5-4bae-99a4-86e6ed35a9dc  100.8G    48% /
sr0    udf      LOTR_THE_FELLOWSHIP_OF_THE_RING 2caf81e800000000                           0   100% /media/bloch/LOTR_THE_FELLOWSHIP_OF_THE_RING
```

My OptiPlex 9010 is slow to boot. I had Ubuntu 19.10 installed and some problems with a blank screen after booting on my Dell P2412H monitor. 
Then I upgraded to 20.04. The boot time seems to be slightly reduced, but still slow. I don't know if the monitor problem is related to the slow boot.

The output of systemd-analyze blame is below:

```
44.890s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                           
29.461s dev-sda5.device                                                      
28.830s systemd-journal-flush.service                                        
24.891s snapd.service                                                        
23.393s networkd-dispatcher.service                                          
20.497s udisks2.service                                                      
20.161s dev-loop15.device                                                    
20.104s dev-loop18.device                                                    
19.874s dev-loop17.device                                                    
19.790s dev-loop19.device                                                    
19.686s dev-loop6.device                                                     
19.551s dev-loop10.device                                                    
19.163s dev-loop5.device                                                     
17.642s dev-loop16.device                                                    
17.553s dev-loop0.device                                                     
17.528s dev-loop12.device                                                    
17.489s dev-loop13.device                                                    
17.429s dev-loop2.device                                                     
17.429s dev-loop4.device                                                     
17.370s dev-loop14.device                                                    
16.999s accounts-daemon.service                                              
16.812s dev-loop8.device                                                     
16.358s dev-loop9.device                                                     
16.300s dev-loop11.device                                                    
15.985s dev-loop3.device                                                     
14.782s dev-loop7.device                                                     
14.051s dev-loop1.device                                                     
11.180s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                   
10.320s ModemManager.service                                                 
 9.707s apport-autoreport.service                                            
 8.384s systemd-udevd.service                                                
 8.036s polkit.service                                                       
 7.970s NetworkManager.service                                               
 7.914s avahi-daemon.service                                                 
 7.490s switcheroo-control.service                                           
 6.158s thermald.service                                                     
 6.156s wpa_supplicant.service                                               
 6.152s systemd-logind.service                                               
 5.195s gpu-manager.service                                                  
 5.188s systemd-resolved.service                                             
 4.668s grub-common.service                                                  
 4.614s apport.service                                                       
 4.322s rsyslog.service                                                      
 3.299s apparmor.service                                                     
 2.992s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                         
 2.885s colord.service                                                       
 2.712s e2scrub_reap.service                                                 
 2.604s snapd.apparmor.service                                               
 2.257s snap-core-8935.mount                                                 
 2.191s snap-core-9066.mount                                                 
 2.100s postfix@-.service                                                    
 2.076s gdm.service                                                          
 2.057s snap-core18-1705.mount                                               
 1.955s snap-core18-1754.mount                                               
 1.745s geoclue.service                                                      
 1.707s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount                              
 1.672s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-71.mount                               
 1.610s fwupd.service                                                        
 1.481s plymouth-read-write.service                                          
 1.472s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-27.mount                               
 1.429s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                       
 1.366s pppd-dns.service                                                     
 1.365s smartmontools.service                                                
 1.299s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1502.mount                              
 1.274s user@1000.service                                                    
 1.226s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                              
 1.200s systemd-modules-load.service                                         
 1.002s snap-mc\x2dinstaller-488.mount                                       
  935ms binfmt-support.service                                               
  904ms snapd.seeded.service                                                 
  903ms snap-mc\x2dinstaller-496.mount                                       
  895ms plymouth-start.service                                               
  820ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                        
  765ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                   
  762ms snap-minetest-1370.mount                                             
  741ms systemd-random-seed.service                                          
  677ms modprobe@drm.service                                                 
  655ms keyboard-setup.service                                               
  640ms systemd-sysusers.service                                             
  638ms systemd-journald.service                                             
  637ms snap-minetest-1521.mount                                             
  585ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                         
  579ms systemd-sysctl.service                                               
  561ms snap-quake\x2dshareware-10.mount                                     
  550ms swapfile.swap                                                        
  503ms snap-quake\x2dshareware-14.mount                                     
  473ms upower.service                                                       
  467ms kerneloops.service                                                   
  450ms ufw.service                                                          
  437ms snap-quakespasm\x2dbeidl-45.mount                                    
  411ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                            
  341ms snap-vlc-1620.mount                                                  
  300ms snap-yamagi\x2dquake2\x2dbeidl-40.mount                              
  261ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount                                         
  215ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                           
  214ms console-setup.service                                                
  191ms snap-vlc-1397.mount                                                  
  161ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                  
  160ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                     
  159ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                               
  159ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                             
  149ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                            
  138ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                 
   97ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                                        
   94ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                        
   93ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                          
   78ms setvtrgb.service                                                     
   76ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                       
   65ms openvpn.service                                                      
    9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                 
    8ms alsa-restore.service                                                 
    3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                        
    2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                              
  746us snapd.socket                                                         
  401us clean-mount-point@media-bloch-LOTR_THE_FELLOWSHIP_OF_THE_RING.service




  bloch@bloch-OptiPlex-9010:~/Desktop$ systemd-analyze
    Startup finished in 4.838s (kernel) + 1min 30.328s (userspace) = 1min 35.166s 
    graphical.target reached after 1min 30.246s in userspace
```

Comment: Consider adding more details about your situation to help others in providing possible solutions. For instance, are you dual-booting with another OS, what kind of drive are you booting from, is the computer's BIOS updated to the latest revision, etc?

Comment: Are you running a Hard drive or SSD? Is the system doing disk error/repair during boot up? Usually you can just watch the boot process and see the process of disk checking/repair by fsck. Also check logs `journalctl -u systemd-fsck*`

Comment: Thanks Czar. 
I did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 last week. (The existing installation was an upgrade from 19.10, and there were even worse problem booting with that version) 
I suspect the problem may have been down to the fact that I re-sized the windows partition after installation.
The boot time is down to about 1min 2seconds reported by systemd, and about 30 seconds unaccounted time after the GRUB selection (down from about 48 seconds).
So the problem is resolved for me - but I don't know if such an unaccounted pause is normal

Answer (score 0):

Newer Radeon cards seem to have issues with Kernels 5.3 and above. My system isn't stable after installing a RX-580 on 19.10 and after a fresh clean/install of Ubuntu 20.04 it still crashes. Old Nvidia GTX-470 had zero issues last month. I haven't found a solution for that, yet.

What type of drive? Hard drive or SSD?

Watch your system boot up by hitting the arrow left or right key. I've had a misconfigured swap file add 1m30s to my boot process.

List the output of *journalctl*

Looks like **dev-sda5.device** is lagging the most. What is your output for /dev/sda5: 
*sudo lsblk -f*

Doesn't hurt to do some quick clean up to your system. 
[What is difference between the options "autoclean", "autoremove" and "clean"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3167/what-is-difference-between-the-options-autoclean-autoremove-and-clean/)

Your snaps are talking what to long to mount. Consider doing the regular install if possible. Found this on snap forum:

As a workaround you can press the “shift” key and move the mouse during bootup this will make the login quicker.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-service-delays-startup-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-4-15-0-24/6205/9

Comment: Thanks Czar for responding. I added the new info to the original question. Yes, before asking I'd actually cut down on my snaps and done some cleaning. 
I'll try the arrow trick now. 

The uncommented lines of my /etc/fstab file are only these:


UUID=09bbb74b-60e5-4bae-99a4-86e6ed35a9dc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

but there is this comment
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation

Comment: I was not able to attach an image. The output of systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg
shows that dev-sda5.device is not the problem. In fact there is no one single outstanding delay in the boot process. The snaps and snapd.apparmor add about 7 seconds.
Systemd reports a 1min 28 secs boot. But the real time from Grub is 2 mins 17 approx.  Is it normal to have such an unaccounted time? The questions here on slow boot don't address this.