# How to "fresh install" a many times upgraded Ubuntu , but keep most apps/settings/home?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

I am currently at 20.10
The systems are upgraded both in terms of hardware and software since at least 14.04 , maybe before - not only LTE, but both .04 and .10 releases.

Having upgraded to very fast hardware (M2 SSD / i9 10900)  it would be very nice to "fresh up" the system, maybe remove tons on unused packages , clean some configuration...

Is there a guide on how to do so ? - I guess it is not as simple as keeping whole "home" , because then lots of old system stuff is kept as well..

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking Ubuntu desktop, or Ubuntu Server.  You can re-install Ubuntu desktop, using the *something-else*, re-using existing partitions and as long as you don't format, it'll note your installed packages, erase system directories, install new system, then add-back the additional packages it noted earlier.  There are some caveats with this (they packages need to be available for the current release, as older packages already existing on your system from prior releases will have been erased.. but it'll do what you want, won't touch user configs (assuming desktop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between the options "autoclean", "autoremove" and "clean"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3167/what-is-difference-between-the-options-autoclean-autoremove-and-clean)

Comment: @guiverc That question isn't fundamental enough to perform all the tasks.