# apt remove command not removing "no longer required dependencies"

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

While trying running the command `apt upgrade`. It shows the list of package that are no longer required.

```
xyz@abc ~ # apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  android-libunwind crda guile-2.2-libs libdav1d5 libdav1d5:i386
  libdns-export1110 libgit2-1.1 libgsasl7 libicu67:i386 libirs-export161
  libisc-export1105 libisccfg-export163 libjim0.79 libjs-highlight.js
  libjs-is-typedarray libjs-typedarray-to-buffer libjs-uglify libllvm13:i386
  libmailutils8 libnode72 libopts25 libpython3.9 libpython3.9-dev
  libssl1.1:i386 libtexlua53 lsp-plugins-jack node-array-union node-array-uniq
  node-execa node-is-typedarray node-merge-stream node-mimic-fn
  node-stealthy-require node-strip-eof node-typedarray-to-buffer ntp
  ntpsec-ntpdig pigz python3-ldb python3-talloc python3.9-dev ruby-uglifier
  sntp
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  android-libboringssl android-libsparse cron-daemon-common dh-dkms
  gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 isympy-commo
```

But when I try to remove them using `apt autoremove`. It doesn't remove any anything.

```
xyz@abc ~ # apt autoremove    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1558 not upgraded.
```

I'm trying to understand why this is happening.
Ideally, if there is no dependency on the packages, `apt autoremove` should remove those packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between the options "autoclean", "autoremove" and "clean"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3167/what-is-difference-between-the-options-autoclean-autoremove-and-clean)

Comment: Please upgrade your system complete. `sudo apt full-upgrade` over 1000 packages are waiting for that.